# Select the first image in a folder selected in the Fiinder

Tags: applescript

I have a script that changes the icon of a folder with the image you select and it works fine but I want to be able to have the script automatically select the first image of the folder and assign that as the image that will be used to create the icon.

This is what I have so far. It is unable to select the image and gives various error messages depending on what I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
set exePath to (path to home folder as text) & "downloads:SetFileIcon"

tell application "Finder"
    set theSelection to selection -- This is a list of selected items, even if only 1 item is selected.
    set theFile to (item 1 of theSelection) as text -- Get the first item in the list. We make it text so we can convert it to a posix path for       SetFileIcon.
    set theimage to item 1 of theSelection
    set imagePath to (path to desktop folder as text) and theimage
end tell


do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of exePath & " -image " & quoted form of POSIX path of imagePath & " -file " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with your script at first glance. First, you’re never asking for the contents of the folder. You set `theFile` to `item 1 of theSelection` and then you set `theimage` to `item 1 of theSelection`. I expect you meant to set `theimage` to item 1 of the `document files of theFile`. Note that `theFile` is actually the selected folder.

Second, “and” is a boolean operation; to concatenate text in AppleScript, use “ & ”. Thus, even if `theimage` contained the image’s name, you would need to use `& theimage`.

However, since you are asking the Finder for the information, the Finder already knows the full path to any particular file. So, once you get an image, you can ask the Finder for the path directly.

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- This is a list of selected items, even if only 1 item is selected.
    set theSelections to the selection
    -- This code assumes that the first selected item is a folder
    set theFolder to the first item of theSelections

    -- we want the first document that is also an image
    set theImages to the document files of theFolder whose kind contains "image"
    set theImage to item 1 of theImages as text

    -- and we want it's path
    set imagePath to POSIX path of theImage
end tell
```